# Delphi + MySQL и Bounds

Tags: mysql, delphi, запрос

Забыл напрочь Delphi.
Стопорнулся на "list index out of bounds"
Делаю что-то такое:

```
begin
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT text_answer FROM `answer` WHERE `question_id` = 1');

  ADOQuery1.Open;

  DataSource1.DataSet:=ADOQuery1;

  RadioButton1.Caption:=AdoQuery1.Fields[0].asString;
  RadioButton2.Caption:=AdoQuery1.Fields[1].asString;
  RadioButton3.Caption:=AdoQuery1.Fields[2].asString;

end;
```

Первый `AdoQuery1.Fields[0].asString;` срабатывает и всё.
В запрос попадает три строки.
SQL-запрос всегда хранит данные в виде массива.
Почему к нему можно обратиться лишь к первому индексу.
Как обратиться к следующим записям выполненного запроса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойство `Fields` позволяет обратиться к ячейкам текущей записи.

В Вашем примере `Fields[0]` - отрабатывает правильно (возвращает первую ячейку текущей записи из набора, т.е. содержимое `text_answer` текущей записи). `Fields[1]` возвращает ошибку, т.к. нет второго столбца.

Перемещение по записям необходимо осуществлять через методы `First`, `Next`

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```pascal
i:=1;
ADOQuery1.Open;
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    // вполне возможно, радиобаттоны лежат на каком-нибудь контроле, например - панели.
    // тогда нужно проводить поиск по компонентам этой панели.
    // в этом примере поиск идет по форме.
    RadioButton:=FindComponent('RadioButton'+IntToStr(i)) as TRadioButton;
    RadioButton.Caption:=ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
    Inc(i);
    ADOQuery1.Next;
  end;
```

Comment: Вот ей богу! Именно об этом и подумал, что перемещаться по массиву обычным Next'ом, но как-то побоялся банальной примитивности. Большое спасибо!